# HMS Drive kit Query and query string

Tags: kotlin, huawei-mobile-services

I'm a beginner developer just starting with HMS. I'm trying to write a code that finds the "profile.json" file, which was previously uploaded to the cloud into the folder "DebtSorter". My code (Kotlin) for it currently looks like:

```
 var fileList: MutableList<File?> = mutableListOf()
        thread {
            try {
                val drive = buildDrive()
                val request = drive.files().list()
                var cursor: String?
                fileList = ArrayList()
                do {
                    var result = request.setQueryParam("fileName contains 'profile'")
                        .setOrderBy("fileName")
                        .setPageSize(10)
                        .setFields("*")
                        .execute()
                    for (file in result.files) {
                        fileList.add(file)
                    }
                    cursor = result.nextCursor
                    request.cursor = cursor
                } while (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(cursor))
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "executeFilesList exception: $e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
        }
        return fileList
```

However, the returned fileList is always empty, even when I upload the file to the root of the cloud. I think I'm messing something up with the query string, because I can upload files just fine. Can someone tell me the syntax and keywords used in the query string, and possibly help me with the code and how to search in a given folder in HMS Drive kit?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

You can also refer to the demo: https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-drive-serverdemo In the demo, the thread executes the method of obtaining the file list directly.

---

Your query parameters is incorrect. You can't define the format of your query string. Please refer to this sample query statement.

(assuming that the ID of folder A is f192358798744098816):

1. To query all files in folder A, run the following statement: **'f192358798744098816' in parentFolder and mimeType != 'application/vnd.huawei-apps.folder'**
2. To query all folders in the recycle bin, run the following statement: **mimeType='application/vnd.huawei-apps.folder' and recycled=true**

The query criteria **'fileId' in parentFolder** and **recycled=true** cannot be used together, that is, a user cannot query files or folders in a specified parent folder in the recycle bin.

For more details, see the [official guide](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/server-public-info-0000001050159641-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050159641__section166302011174612).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the end, my main issue was the inclusion of the thread, but I am thankful for you directing me to the Refernces. I was looking all over for them

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the problem was with creating the `thread`. Since the thread is asynchronous and I created the `fileList` variable before the thread, modified it in the thread and returned it after the thread, the actual modification happened after the method already returned with the empty `fileList`. I took out the lines with `thread` and put the method call into a thread. This solved it.